# поисковый solr запрос на поисковый агрегатор

Tags: c#, http, solr

Пытаюсь сделать запрос на выборку статей с сервиса по сбору статей

```
GET /search/?query=<term>&skip=<skip num>&limit=<limit num>
```

где `query=<term>`

Это запрос на языке solr.
Как правильно записывать команды solr в url?

Answer (score 1):

```
// #r "System.Web"
using System.Web;
using System.Net;

var q = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("query=&skip=10&limit=");
q["query"] = "тут команды solr";
q["limit"] = "5";
var c = new WebClient();
c.QueryString = q;
var s = c.DownloadString("http://агрегатор.ru/search");
```